# Find and replace an element's class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The platform that I'm currently using does not allow me to change much of the HTML that's been designed, so to get around this, I need to use JQuery to find and replace a div with another div (or perhaps in simpler terms (incase I'm getting something wrong here), find text in the HTML and replace it with other text).

So, the original is:

```
<div class="title-desc-wrapper has-main-image" data-content-field="main-image">
```

I need it to be replaced with:

```
<div class="title-desc-wrapper no-main-image" data-content-field="main-image">
```

If anyone has any insight into how to do this, or could show me how, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `$('.has-main-image').toggleClass('has-main-image no-main-image')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the class `has-main-image` and remove the class `no-main-image`:

```
$('.title-desc-wrapper.has-main-image').removeClass('has-main-image').addClass('no-main-image');
```

..or you could use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to essentially replace the class:

```
$('.title-desc-wrapper.has-main-image').toggleClass('has-main-image no-main-image');
```

Comment: Worked beautifully once I put it in window onload. Thank you so much!

Comment: do you know how I could use something like this to completely remove a div: 
<div class="main-image-wrapper">
etc (can't include what's under this here due to text limitations)

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) `.toggleClass()`

```
$(".has-main-image").toggleClass("has-main-image no-main-image");
```

Or simply you can remove the "has-main-image" and add the "no-main-image" class

```
$(".title-desc-wrapper.has-main-image").removeClass("has-main-image").addClass("no-main-image");
```

Or if you need animation, you can use [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) `.switchClass()`

```
$(".title-desc-wrapper.has-main-image").switchClass("has-main-image","no-main-image", duration, easing , complete )
```

I hope that helps, good luck