# Remove a div class using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use JQuery to remove the following div from the HTML.

```
<div class="main-image content-fill" style="overflow: hidden;">
 <img data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a8e280e4b0222e1cd90549/53bb1263e4b053aeb1247ba7/5657e934e4b08c62b9d0afa6/1448853091831/" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a8e280e4b0222e1cd90549/53bb1263e4b053aeb1247ba7/5657e934e4b08c62b9d0afa6/1448853091831/" data-image-dimensions="600x338" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="How To Pick a Pumpkin and the History of Halloween " class="" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/53a8e280e4b0222e1cd90549/53bb1263e4b053aeb1247ba7/5657e934e4b08c62b9d0afa6/1448853091831/?format=2500w" data-image-resolution="2500w" style="top: -61px; left: 0px; width: 792px; height: 447px; position: relative;">
</div>
```

I think this is quite similar to another question that I have posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988513/find-and-replace-an-elements-class-using-jquery/33989219#33989219), but I couldn't seem to successfully adapt it to this situation.

If anybody has any insight and can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Note that the "img data-src, data-image, alt and src change from time to time so likely I'd want to remove all instances of the div class.

Comment: To remove the elements from the document, [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Answer (score 2):

using this :

```
$(".main-image.content-fill").remove();
```

And if you only want to remove the content from this DIV, you can use EMPTY method :

```
 $(".main-image.content-fill").empty();
```